# ZenOSS webinterface connecting

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall, zenoss

I'm having a problem with ZenOss. I installed the centos stack installer on Centos 5.5 x64. De installation succeeded and no errors where displayed. But when I tried to surft to the ip address it doesn't respond. Then I added an exception to the iptables firewall. But still no response. Can anyone tell me what other problem there could be?

I used these lines for the firewall exception

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 8080 -j ACCEPT

The output of iptables -L

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:webcache 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:webcache 

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp any 
ACCEPT     esp  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     ah   --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251         udp dpt:mdns 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:ipp 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ipp 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

or

```
iptables -I RH-Firewall-1-INPUT 7 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

or edit /etc/sysconfig/iptables

Comment: If I want to add SNMP ports. Do I need to use iptables -I INPUT 2 -p tcp --dport 161 -j ACCEPT and iptables -I INPUT 3 -p udp --dport 161 -j ACCEPT?

Comment: Yes, you need add access rules to 161 port.

Comment: I've been a bit lazy learning IP tables, I use the system-config-network-security-tui to add the port. Seems to work fine. I'm pretty sure you're going to want to open port 162 (trap receiver). 161 is for the SNMP daemon which can respond to OID requests.